# Mapping from Exception to ExceptT

Tags: haskell, exception, lazy-evaluation, monad-transformers

I am reading a chapter about exceptions so I decided to experiment and map an Exception to the ExceptT monad transformer. My function getInt can read an integer from a console and report exceptions as Left "what's wrong":

```
getInt :: ExceptT String IO Int
getInt = ExceptT $ do
    Right . read <$> getLine
    `catch` \(e :: ErrorCall) -> return . Left . show $ e
```

I tried it, unfortunately the exception was not caught, laziness is mocking me. OK, let me make it strict with `seq`.

```
getInt :: ExceptT String IO Int
getInt = ExceptT $ do
    read <$> getLine >>= seq <*> return . Right
    `catch` \(e :: ErrorCall) -> return . Left . show $ e
```

The result is: Left "Prelude.read: no parse". Now it works!

My question here is - is this the right way how to map an Exception to the ExceptT?

Comment: You could use the strict application `$!`. Also, it is usually desirable to use mtl style interface (MonadError in this case) instead of a concrete monad transformer stack.

Comment: But Hoogle tells me about MonadError: Deprecated: Use Control.Monad.Except instead

Comment: Yes, there's a MonadError inside `Control.Monad.Except` as well.

Comment: interesting experiment, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is indeed to force the evaluation of `read`. This can be done more elegantly with the call-by-value application `$!`

```
getInt :: ExceptT SomeException IO Int
getInt = ExceptT $ liftIO $ try @SomeException $ do
  i <- getLine
  pure $! read i
```

It is usually better to parameterize the underlying monad (for testability and reusability reasons), so we could write

```
getInt :: (MonadError SomeException m, MonadIO m) => m Int
getInt = liftEither =<< liftIO $ try @SomeException $ do
  i <- getLine
  pure $! read i
```

insdead of a concrete monad transformer stack `ExceptT SomeException IO Int`